# Upload Microsoft Excel Workbook with Many Sheets into Azure ML Studio

Tags: excel, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to upload my `Excel` Workbook into Azure Machine Learning Studio. The reason is I have some data that I would like to join into my other `.csv` files to create a training data set. 
When I upload my `Excel`, I don't get `.xlsx`, or `.xls`, but other extensions such as `.csv`, `.txt` etc..

This is how it looks,
[image]

I uploaded anyways and now, I am getting weird characters. How can I get excel workbook uploaded and get my sheets, so, I can join data and do, data preparation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the workbook as a (set of) CSV file(s) and upload them separately.

A CSV file, a '[Comma Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)' file, is exactly that. A flat file with some values separated by a comma. If you load an Excel file it will mess up since there's way more information in an Excel file than just values separated by comma's. Have a look at `File` -> `Save as` -> `Save as type` where you can select 'CSV (comma delimited) (*.csv)'

*Disclaimer: no, it's not always a comma...*

> In addition, the term "CSV" also denotes some closely related delimiter-separated formats that use different field delimiters. These include tab-separated values and space-separated values. A delimiter that is not present in the field data (such as tab) keeps the format parsing simple. These alternate delimiter-separated files are often even given a .csv extension despite the use of a non-comma field separator.

**Edit**
So apparently Excel files *are* supported: [Supported data sources for Azure Machine Learning data preparation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/data-prep-appendix2-supported-data-sources)

*Excel (.xls/.xlsx)*
Read an Excel file one sheet at a time by specifying sheet name or number.

But also, only UTF-8 is supported: [Import Data - Technical notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/import-data#bkmk_Notes)

> Azure Machine Learning requires UTF-8 encoding. If the data you are importing uses a different encoding, or was exported from a data source that uses a different default encoding, various problems might appear in the text.

Comment: I was going to post this in question that I could go in manual route saving each sheet as `.csv`. However, is there any other workaround? Because, when these sheets change, I have to manually convert them into .csv and then upload them separate. I have about 27 sheets!

Comment: You could write a tool which does this for you... Or create a tool/console app/function that takes in the Excel file and uploads the data. Maybe you could even do it _from the Excel file..._

Comment: Some other resources I am finding after posting this, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814254/how-to-import-xls-into-azure-database) and [2](http://failedturing.blogspot.com/2015/11/migrating-appengine-datastore-entities_25.html?_sm_au_=iVVFSFq52tPQQsJF)